# Show Toast on method Response NanoHTTPD

Tags: android, android-context, toast, nanohttpd

I use `NanoHTTPD` ([this](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)) to make simple server. I follow [this](https://tutocodem.wordpress.com/nanohttpd/) tutorial too for testing. I search deep inside the issue on its GitHub but I haven't found any solution. I only want is to show a simple `Toast` when someone open the address given from the my project in their browser.

Here is the code for my Server.class :

```
public class Server extends NanoHTTPD {

private static Server server = null;
Context context;

@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    String msg = "My Server in Android\n";
//        context = ProgramProperties.getAppContext();

    if (session.getMethod() == Method.GET) {
        Map<String,String> headers = session.getHeaders();
        if (headers.get("username") != null) {
            String username = headers.get("username");
            msg += "Hi, " + username;   /* Output for browser */
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Receive Connection, Hello " + username , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            msg+="Wrong headers parameters";
//                Toast.makeText(context, "Receive Connection with null header", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return newFixedLengthResponse(msg + "</body></html>");
}

private Server() throws IOException {
    super(8080);

}

public static Server getServer() throws IOException{
    if(server == null){

        server = new Server();
    }
    return server;
}
}
```

I have one singleton class with static Context so I can guarantee the `context` from code above is not null.

The problem is, when I comment line `Toast` like above , everything is work like normal. The browser from user show the output from `Response` method. But when I used `Toast`, it's like the Android not send the data into browser, so the browser not show the properly output.

### Edit

Here is my log:

```
02-14 12:31:54.574 25609-26777/com.test.vhp.testproject E/NanoHTTPD: Communication with the client broken, or an bug in the handler code java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() 
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200) 
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114) 
 at android.widget.Toast$TN$3.<init>(Toast.java:350)
 at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:350) 
 at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:107) 
 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:263) 
 at Server.serve(Server.java:34) at NanoHTTPD.NanoHTTPD$1.handle(NanoHTTPD.java:376) 
 at NanoHTTPD.NanoHTTPD$1.handle(NanoHTTPD.java:372) 
 at NanoHTTPD.NanoHTTPD.handle(NanoHTTPD.java:535) 
 at NanoHTTPD.HTTPSession.execute(HTTPSession.java:421) 
 at NanoHTTPD.ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:75) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
02-14 12:32:04.882 25609-26932/com.test.vhp.testproject E/NanoHTTPD: Communication with the client broken, or an bug in the handler code java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() 
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200) 
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114) 
 at android.widget.Toast$TN$3.<init>(Toast.java:350) 
 at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:350) 
 at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:107) 
 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:263) at Server.serve(Server.java:34)
 at NanoHTTPD.NanoHTTPD$1.handle(NanoHTTPD.java:376)
 at NanoHTTPD.NanoHTTPD$1.handle(NanoHTTPD.java:372) 
 at NanoHTTPD.NanoHTTPD.handle(NanoHTTPD.java:535) 
 at NanoHTTPD.HTTPSession.execute(HTTPSession.java:421)
 at NanoHTTPD.ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:75) 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: To Show toast you need context. Not sure but Application class can give you context,

Comment: @farhana yes I knew. So I make one singleton class extend with Application to get the `Context`.

Comment: You may do one this you can make constructer which carries context of Activity where you are using this class object. In class, your are creating context object but you are not initializing it, You can do it with constructor.

Comment: @farhana I did but the `Toast` still didnt show and the browser not show the properly output. I realy dont have idea about this

Comment: Have you checked Exception?

Comment: when you see the logcat, do you see the the line like: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`?

Comment: @farhana it not go to Exception at all

Comment: @pskink yes the error is that. I just debug now. What its mean?

Comment: so first of all: post the complete stacktrace, otherwise how people can tell you anything? second ask google for: `android toast background thread`, 3rd use `Log.d` for logging, not `Toast`s

Comment: @pskink oh sorry. But I think you dont know my purpose. I want make some notification lie Toast, DialogAlert or something when someone trigger the address in browser. So I really need simple example with Toast not just with Log only. Ok thanks very much, I will find about the error in my logcat

Comment: so did you ask google for: `android toast background thread` ?

Comment: @pskink yes I doing, Thanks for advice

Comment: @pskink maybe you want make an asnwer. Its work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pskink comment above. I have done with this problem. Googling with this keyword `android toast background thread` and I found the solution. Below the code :

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Receive Connection, Hello " + username , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show a Toast() in the serve() of NanoHttpd as that is executed in a thread.

Indeed you will not see an exception. They are already catched by nano.

Answer (score 0):

IMO problem with your `Context context`
try `getApplicationContext()` instead `context` like

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Receive Connection, Hello " + username , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**OR**

so create `Constructor` in `Server` class

```
public Server (Context ctx){

this.context = ctx;

}
```

and call this constructor to initialize Context object in your `Activity Class` like

```
Server server = new Server (MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: hi @Omi, use directly `getApplicationContext` in non Activity class is not possible. So I make a singleton class `private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProgramProperties.context = getApplicationContext();
    }` . So I can say `context` in my code above is `getApplicationContext` too

Comment: Second way from your advice is not work too :( I try it before